# rails turbolinks issue: create.js.erb/update.js.erb runs again on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I have a rails app with simple task model. Task creation happens with AJAX via bootstrap modal on the task index page.

Task creation/update seems to be working fine with appending the @task partial with create.js.erb, but if after creation or update I go to another page then get back to task index page then the create.js.erb and update.js.erb run again.

I can see it since I'm using fadeIn for updating and creating as well. This means for creation there is the same task twice, first loaded by the server on GET request (what I need) and one gets 'fadeIn' because of the create.js.erb. For update the freshly updated task disappears and gets 'fadeIn' as task index page loads again.

I tried jquery.turbolinks, but with that I had the same task 3 times on creation and double update fadeIn for update, so it just made it worse.
Also tried <%= "data-no-turbolink" if request.post? %> in body tag in app layout, but no effect with that one.

app.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require chat
//= require refile
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require private_pub
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

views/tasks/create.js.erb

```
var ready = function () {

    //empty modal error list
    $("ul.errors").html("");
    <% if @task.errors.any? %>
        //modal error messages get inserted via AJAX
        $('.alert-danger').show();
        $('ul.errors').show();
        <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"));
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        //hiding modal on creation and setting values to zero for optional new modal
        $('ul.errors').hide();
        $('.alert-danger').hide();
        $("#newtask").modal('hide');
        $(".task_name_company").val('');
        $(".contentarea").val('');
        $(".task_deadline").val('');

        //different div class for different partials (.newtaskinsert and .newtaskinsert2 divs are on different pages) + table rows get inserted into view via AJAX
        $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render @task %>');
        $(".newtaskinsert2").prepend('<%= j render partial: "tasks/task_between", locals: { task: @task } %>');
        $("#task_<%= @task.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);

        //26= pagination(12)*every task has 2 tr(2)+ extra task that must be hidden(2)=12*2+2
        var n = $('tr').length;
        if (n > 26) {
            $("tr").slice((-2*(n-26)/2)-1).fadeOut(500);
        };
    <% end %>
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

views/tasks/update.js.erb

```
var ready = function () {

    $("ul.errors").html("");
    <% if @task.errors.any? %>
        //modal error messages get inserted via AJAX
        $('.alert-danger').show();
        $('ul.errors').show();
        <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"));
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        $('ul.errors').hide();
        $('.alert-danger').hide();
        $('#updatetask_<%= @task.id %>').modal('hide');

        $('#task_<%= @task.id %>').fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render @task %>');
            $(".newtaskinsert2").prepend('<%= j render partial: "tasks/task_between", locals: { task: @task } %>');
    });
     <% end %>

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

task.js

```
  var ready = function() {

    //choosing user on task creation
    $('.task_name_company').autocomplete({
    source: "/users/:user_id/tasknamecompanies"
    });

    //unfocus the newtask button after modal closing
    $('#newtask').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.newbutton').one('focus', function (e) {
        $(this).blur();
        });
    });

    //when modal closes error messages get hidden
    $('#newtask').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.alert-danger').hide();
    });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Comment: have you tried removing one of `$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);`? Seems to me that because of that it gets called twice

Comment: I tried, but with only the $(document).on("page:load", ready) modal doesn't get closed when I submit the task. I found this solution in raliscasts, so should be fine. Btw, do I have to use this in all the js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your `create.js.erb` and `update.js.erb` I don't think you need to include it as a `var ready`.

Just include without the `function()` wrapped around it:

<strike>`var ready = function () {`</strike>

```
$("ul.errors").html("");
<% if @task.errors.any? %>
    //modal error messages get inserted via AJAX
    $('.alert-danger').show();
    $('ul.errors').show();
    <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"));
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    $('ul.errors').hide();
    $('.alert-danger').hide();
    $('#updatetask_<%= @task.id %>').modal('hide');

    $('#task_<%= @task.id %>').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render @task %>');
        $(".newtaskinsert2").prepend('<%= j render partial: "tasks/task_between", locals: { task: @task } %>');
    });
 <% end %>
```

<strike>`});`</strike>

Therefor also remove <strike>`$(document).ready(ready);$(document).on('page:load');`</strike> in those files.

And in your `task.js` you could try using `$(document).on("ready page:load", ready);` as one function calling.

Comment: You are right! I just solved the problem 10 mins ago :). I don't need anything in js.erb files, it's executed when clicking on submit button. For the simple js files, I have yet to play with that. At the moment everything is working fine if I don't use //= require jquery.turbolinks

Comment: Glad to hear :). turbolinks is sometimes just tricky, even though it looks easy ;)